# Error: pattern must be a RegExp

Tags: regex, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I need to accept a mobile number as input of web-service, but i am facing following issue while validating with Joi framework.

Joi says:

```
Error: pattern must be a RegExp
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/gaurav/Gaurav-Drive/code/nodejsWorkspace/ragchews/node_modules/joi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:524:11)
    at internals.String.regex (/home/gaurav/Gaurav-Drive/code/nodejsWorkspace/ragchews/node_modules/joi/lib/string.js:107:10)
    at /home/gaurav/Gaurav-Drive/code/nodejsWorkspace/ragchews/src/validators/userValidator.js:10:40
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gaurav/Gaurav-Drive/code/nodejsWorkspace/ragchews/src/validators/userValidator.js:13:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

for validation:

```
var userProfileValidation = function(){
    return {
        payload : {
            uid: Joi.string().required().alphanum().length(userConfigs.UID_LENGTH),
            mobile_num: Joi.string().required().regex('^[0-9]*$').length(userConfigs.RMN_LENGTH) //for this guy
        }
    };
}();
```

I checked the regex on [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html) and it seems to work fine for atleast some inputs. I don't understand why joi is throwing this error.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `/` on the ends of the pattern: `/^[0-9]*$/`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, as documented [here (link)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.0/API.md#stringregexpattern-name--options) the *Joi framework* expects here not a *regex pattern*, but an **actual regex**. i.e.: you should use:

```
Joi.string().required().regex(/^[0-9]*$/) [...]
```

... instead of:

```
Joi.string().required().regex('^[0-9]*$') [...]
```